# how to optimize postgresql81 for a hug query but not a complicated one?

Tags: configuration, postgresql, optimization, query

i have a query which execution takes 15s on the server.
the server is bi-xeon 5130 (2GHz) with 2GB of RAM and 160GB of scsi hardrive in RAID.
Database is PostgreSQL 8.1 on Debian 4 etch.

This query is executed by an ERP (openerp), so i can't change or modify it.
i can test it as i want,i can reproduce the long time as i want, i got it in the log file and reproduce the case into pgadmin.

Copy/pasted into a txt file, the simple query need 170Kb to be stored (just the text query).

During the execution, linux (by 'top' commandline) tell me that postgres use 99-100% of the CPU but only 6% of RAM.

So, how can i increase the performance of postgres to gain time in this query execution.
a parameter somewhere ? in Postgres ? in linux ?

The query is like this:

```
SELECT
    id
FROM
    sale_order_line
WHERE
    (state IN ('confirmed', 'confirmed_wait', 'manquant'))
    AND
    (id IN (27405, 27399, 16583, 27395, XXX))
ORDER BY 
    id DESC LIMIT 50;
```

[replace the XXX by a list of 20000 id ! ]

yes this is a monster query but not a complicated one , very simple in fact.

thanks for help.
i search for a long time (2 weeks already...)

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of steps to take here:

- Optimise the PostgreSQL config so it uses the correct amount of your system resources (see [this article](http://www.anchor.com.au/hosting/dedicated/Tuning_PostgreSQL_on_your_Dedicated_Server) I wrote for a previous employer for my full set of tips on this front);
- You need to optimize the database schema -- specifically, the indexes therein -- to make the database run as efficiently as possible.  For that, see [this article on query tuning](http://www.anchor.com.au/hosting/dedicated/SQL_Query_Optimisation) written by a colleague of mine at said former job.  It covers both MySQL and PostgreSQL, but just the relevant bits should get you along the way to the ultimate solution.